# How to use npm workspace

Tags: npm, workspace, npm-workspaces

I develop my app by using npm workspace.but I am totally novice to this concept so that I would like to understand npm workspace behavior

```
.
├── package.json
└── packages
    ├── a
    │   └── package.json
    ├── b
    │   └── package.json
    └── c
        └── package.json
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

My question is

①what happens when I run `npm install` in root directory ?
All the packages are installed in each repository ? or root directory ?

②`npm install` in each project is not recommended ?

if someone has opinion, will you please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So long as all packages have the same version of dependencies listed (e.g. `thing@1.0.0`), then `npm install` run from the root of your repository will add the dependency into the root `node_modules` directory.

If one of your packages (e.g. `packages/c`) has a different version of a dependency (e.g. `thing@1.0.1`) then that would appear in `packages/2/node_modules`)

In theory you are using npm workspaces to ensure some consistency across packages, therefore ensuring your versions are consistent will mean `node_modules` is only ever created in the root of your repository